# Can't save my file inside a zip archive

Tags: c#, uwp

I made myself some code that is supposed to make a Zip file containing another file. This file is created from a canvas. But the zip file that is created is empty and doesn't contain anything. The exception also isn't thrown. Any idea what might be wrong?

```
var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Extended sketchpad", new[] { ".exsk" });

Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if (null != file)
{
    try
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                var giffile = archive.CreateEntry("layer.gif");
                using (Stream entryStream = giffile.Open())
                {
                    await MyInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(entryStream.AsOutputStream());
                }
            }

            using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream finalStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                finalStream.Size = 0;

                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                memoryStream.CopyTo(finalStream.AsStreamForWrite());
            }
        }
        //MainPage.NotifyUser("File has been saved!", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //MainPage.NotifyUser(ex.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write to file directly?

```
using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        var giffile = archive.CreateEntry("layer.gif");

        using (Stream entryStream = giffile.Open())
        {
            await MyInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(entryStream.AsOutputStream());
        }
    }
}
```